# $sort and $slice along with $addToSet in php mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$ret  = $this->topusers->update (
                array("keyword" => $key),
                array('$addToSet' => array("users" => array('$each' => array(array('uname' => $uname, 'counter' => $counter))),
                                                      '$sort' => array('counter'=>intval(1))
                                                      '$slice' => intval(-2)
                                                        )),
                array("upsert" => true, "w" => 1)
        );
        var_dump($ret);
```

What is wrong with this code ? Tried with $push as well. Will get Modified field name may not start with $ error.

Please help

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is the expected result?

Comment: It is supposed to sort and slice.. its not doing. Right now it gives an error 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Modified field name may not start with $' in ....

Answer (score 1):

Found a work-around. To get the mongo command directly working. Full native php version is still eluding me..

This will allow you to update a collection with sorted array and limit the array size as well.

Hope its useful for someone else as well.

```
 $command = 'db.topusers.update( { keyword: "'.$key.'" },'.
                            '{ $push: { users: { $each : [{ name: "'.$uname.'", counter: '.intval($counter).'}],'.
                                     ' $sort: { counter: 1 },'.
                                     ' $slice: -2'.
                                    '}'.
                         '}'.
                '},'.
                '{upsert : true})';
    $this->db->execute($command);
```

Comment: Hi user3009438, finally did you found another solution or why doesn't work with PHP driver? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
   $ret  = $this->topusers->update (
   array("keyword" => $key),
   array("$addToSet" => array("users" => array("$each" => array(array('uname' => $uname, 'counter' => $counter))),
   "$sort" => array('counter'=>intval(1)),
   "$slice" => intval(-2)
   )),
   array("upsert" => true, "w" => 1)
   );
   var_dump($ret);
```

Comment: Ok, if then what is your expected output?

Comment: Expect it to work. Update the collection with sorted limited number array

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the array()s incorrectly.
Try this:

```
$ret  = $test->topusers->update (
    array("keyword" => $key),
    array(
        '$addToSet' => array(
            "users" => array(
                '$each' => array(array('uname' => $uname, 'counter' => $counter)),
                '$sort' => array('counter'=>intval(1)),
                '$slice' => intval(-2)
            )
        ),
    ),
    array("upsert" => true, "w" => 1)
);
```